# How to combine two variables in javascript with comma in between?

Tags: javascript

I want to combine two variables using JavaScript.

```
var width = window.screen.width;
var height = window.screen.height;
```

so it would have a var like

```
var width_height =
```

How would I combine both of them with one variable and have a output as example below

```
1600,900
```

Comment: `var var3 = var1 + "," + var2`

Comment: Just change the variable names. It might be worthwhile to invest time reading a tutorial to understand some base concepts.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just concate them like

```
var1 + "," + var2
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QGQFy/2/)**

Update: As you have updated question and as per comments. Use

```
var width_height  = window.screen.width + "," + window.screen.height;
```

**[Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QGQFy/4/)**

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't mean to click send yet, I updated my question to a example I'm trying to do.

Comment: how would you make the one line all together minus var1 & var2 so it has 1 var?

Comment: @AbbyE, see http://jsfiddle.net/QGQFy/4/ just use `var width_height  = window.screen.width + "," + window.screen.height;`

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript you can concatenate Strings

```
var a = "A";
var b = "B";
```

in various ways

**Using the +-Operator**

```
var c = a + "," + b;
```

**using concat**

```
var c = a.concat(",").concat(b);
```

**Using join**

```
var c = [a,b].join(",");
```

Comment: Using join can be this easy: [a,b].join(',');

Comment: or simple template var sring: var combine_variable = `${var3}${var2}-${var1}`;